# How best to fill a vector of vectors (avoiding wasting memory and unnecessary allocations & de-allocations)?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, allocation

I want to fill a vector of vectors when individual vectors can have different `size()`, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::vector<big_data_type> > table;
std::vector<big_data_type> tmp;
for(auto i=0; i!=4242; ++i) {
  tmp = make_vector(i);              // copy elison; calls new[] only for i=0
  table.push_back(tmp);              // copy         calls new[] each time
}
```

My main issue is to avoid wasting memory on unused capacity. So my first question is:

**Q1** Will the copy (made inside `push_back`) have `capacity()` == `size()` (what I want), or preserve whatever `tmp` had, or is this implementation dependent / undefined?

I was considering to move the individual `vector`s into the `table`

```
  table.push_back(std::move(tmp));   // move
```

but that would surely preserve the `capacity` and hence waste memory. Moreover, this doesn't avoid the allocation of each individual vector, it only moves it into another place (inside `make_vector` instead of `push_back`).

**Q2** I was wondering what difference it makes to omit the variable `tmp`, resulting in the more elegant looking code (2 instead of 5 lines):

```
for(auto i=0; i!=4242; ++i)
  table.push_back(make_vector(i));   // move!
```

My initial thought is that this will construct and destruct another temporary at each iteration and hence generate many calls to `new[]` and `delete[]` (which will essentially re-use the same memory). However, in addition this will call the moving version of `push_back` and hence waste memory (see above). Correct?

**Q3** Is it possible that the compiler "optimizes" my former code into this latter form and thus uses moving instead of copying (resulting in wasting memory)?

**Q4** If I'm correct, it seems to me that all this implies that moving data automatically for temporary objects is a mixed blessing (as it prevents compacting). Is there are any way to explicitly suppress moving in the last code snipped, i.e. something like

```
for(auto i=0; i!=4242; ++i)
  table.push_back(std::copy(make_vector(i)));   // don't move!
```

Comment: Nested [`std::generatr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) (or [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n)) calls?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Nope, doesn't help. `make_vector` uses `push_back` (actually `emplace_back`), and doesn't know the size in advance (required for `generate`)

Comment: If you can use C++11, you could use two iterators constructor along with `emplace_back`: `table.emplace_back(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());`

Comment: @jrok Hmm. This calls a constructor of `vector` instead of `operator=`. Isn't this effectively the same? Why should it be better?

Comment: I understand you want to drop the excess capacity. Using two iterator constructor sort of hides the information about capacity.

Comment: What does `make_vector` do?  Who is calling `new[]`?  Are you assuming `std::vector` uses `new[]`?

Comment: @Yakk `make_vector` calls `vector::reserve(some_large_number)` and then adds elements. If the vector has not enough capacity, that allocates memory, whether explicitly calling `new[]` or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @jrok. good point. So this seems the best solution (minimum memory usage at smallest number of allocations/de-allocations). Can you provide an answer?

Comment: `template<typename T> typename std::remove_reference<T>::type make_copy( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }` or `template<typename T> T block_move( T&& t ) { return t; }` might help you if you want to block `move`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1 Will the copy (made inside push_back) have capacity() == size() (what I want), or preserve whatever tmp had, or is this implementation dependent / undefined?

The standard never sets maximums for capacity, only minimums. That said, most implementations will have `capacity() == size()` for a fresh vector copy or capacity slightly rounded up to the blocksize of the allocator implementation.

> Q2 I was wondering what difference it makes to omit the variable tmp, resulting in the more elegant looking code.

The result is to move into `table` instead of copying.

> Q3 Is it possible that the compiler "optimizes" my former code into this latter form and thus uses moving instead of copying (resulting in wasting memory)?

It's possible but very unlikely. The compiler would have to prove that moving isn't observably different from copying, which is challenging enough that to my knowledge no current compiler tries.

> Q4 If I'm correct, it seems to me that all this implies that moving data automatically for temporary objects is a mixed blessing (as it prevents compacting).

Moving is a speed optimization, not necessarily a space optimization. Copying *may* reduce the space, but it definitely *will* increase the processing time.

If you want to optimize space, your best bet is to use `shrink_to_fit`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<big_data_type> > table;
for(auto i=0; i!=4242; ++i) {
  std::vector<big_data_type> tmp = make_vector(i); // copy elison
  tmp.shrink_to_fit();                             // shrink
  table.push_back(std::move(tmp));                 // move
}
```

## EDIT: In-depth analysis.

Assumptions:

- `table` will have its space reserved in advance since its size is known, we
  thus focus on allocations and deallocations of the `vector<big_data_type>`s
  that are returned from `make_vector`, stored temporarily in `tmp`,
  and finally in `table`.
- The return value of `make_vector(i)` may or may not have `capacity == size`.
  This analysis treats `make_vector` as opaque and ignores any allocations
  necessary to build the returned vector.
- A default-constructed vector has 0 capacity.
- `reserve(n)` sets capacity to exactly `n` if and only if `n > capacity()`.
- `shrink_to_fit()` sets `capacity == size`. It may or may not be implemented
  to require a copy of the entire vector contents.
- The vector copy constructor sets `capacity == size`.
- `std::vector` may or may not provide the strong exception guarantee for
  copy assignment.

I'll parameterize the analysis on two positive integers: `N`, the number of
vectors that will be in `table` at the end of the algorithm (4242 in the OP),
and `K`: the total number of `big_data_type` objects contained in all vectors
produced by `make_vector` during the course of the algorithm.

## Your Technique

```
std::vector<std::vector<big_data_type> > table;
table.reserve(N);
std::vector<big_data_type> tmp;
for(auto i=0; i!=N; ++i) {
  tmp = make_vector(i); // #1
  table.push_back(tmp); // #2
}
// #3
```

**For C++11**

At #1, since `tmp` is already constructed, RVO/copy elision cannot occur. On
every pass through the loop the return value is assigned to `tmp`. The
assignment is a move: old data in `tmp` will be destroyed (except on the
first iteration when `tmp` is empty) and the contents of the return value from
`make_vector` moved into `tmp` with no copying taking place. `tmp` has `capacity == size`
if and only if `make_vector`'s return value has that property.

At #2, `tmp` is copied into `table`. The newly constructed copy in `table` has
`capacity == size` as desired. At #3 `tmp` presumably leaves scope and its
storage is deallocated.

Total allocations/deallocations: `N`. All allocations at #2, `N - 1` deallocations at #1, and one at #3.

Total copies (of `big_data_type` objects): `K`.

**For Pre-C++11**

At #1, since `tmp` is already constructed, RVO/copy elision cannot occur. On
every pass through the loop the return value is assigned to `tmp`. This
assignment requires an allocation and a deallocation if either (a) the
implementation provides the strong guarantee, or (b) `tmp` is too small to
contain all the elements in the returned vector. In any case the elements must
be copied individually. At the end of the full expression, the temporary object
that holds the return value from `make_vector` is destroyed, resulting in a
deallocation.

At #2, `tmp` is copied into `table`. The newly constructed copy in `table` has
`capacity == size` as desired. At #3 `tmp` presumably leaves scope and its
storage is deallocated.

Total allocation/deallocations: `N` + 1 to 2 * `N`. 1 to `N` allocations at #1, `N` at #2;
                    `N` to 2 * `N` - 1 deallocations at #1, and one at #3.

Total copies: 2 * `K`. `K` at #1 and `K` at #2.

## My Technique (C++11-only)

```
std::vector<std::vector<big_data_type> > table;
table.reserve(N);
for(auto i=0; i!=N; ++i) {
  auto tmp = make_vector(i);          // #1
  tmp.shrink_to_fit();                // #2
  table.emplace_back(std::move(tmp)); // #3
}
```

At #1 `tmp` is freshly constructed from the return value of `make_vector`, so
RVO/copy elision is possible. Even if the implementation of `make_vector`
impedes RVO, `tmp` will be move-constructed resulting in no allocations,
deallocations, or copies.

At #2 `shrink_to_fit` may or may not require a single allocation and
deallocation, depending on whether the return value from `make_vector` already
has the `capacity == size` property. If allocation/deallocation occurs, the
elements may or may not be copied depending on quality of implementation.

At #3 the contents of `tmp` are moved into a freshly constructed vector in
`table`. No allocations/deallocations/copies are performed.

Total allocations/deallocations: 0 or `N`, all at #2 if and only if `make_vector` does not return vectors with `capacity == size`.
Total copies: 0 or `K`, all at #2 if and only if `shrink_to_fit` is implemented as a copy.

If the implementor of `make_vector` produces vectors with the `capacity == size`
property and the standard library implements `shrink_to_fit` optimally, there
are no news/deletes and no copies.

## Conclusions

Worst case performance of My Technique is the same as expected case performance
of Your Technique. My technique is conditionally optimal.

Comment: Your last suggestion amounts to lots's of calls to `new[]` (3 per iteration: 1 in `make_vector` calling `resize()`, 1 in `shrink_to_fit`, 1 in `push_back`) and `delete[]` (2 per iteration)

Comment: @Walter You are *copying* now. It results in less or the same overhead as your current approach.

Comment: You are *copying* too (in `shrink_to_fit`), but you call `new[]` and `delete[]` each twice more per iteration.

Comment: @Walter I'm confused: the question states that your goal is to minimize space, but your comments suggest you want to minimize calls to `new` and `delete`. Before I write a book here, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want to minimise memory, but avoid *unnecessary* calls to `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: @Walter Ok, book written: Detailed analysis of the original approach and my approach, characterized in terms of number of allocations/deallocations and copies of `big_data_type`.

Comment: Assuming that `make_vector` never returns `capacity()==size()`. (1) IMHO, copy elision is possible in #1 in my code: `tmp` is just passed to `make_vector` similar to passing a reference. (2) Your analysis of my code is *incorrect*, as the number of allocations minus the number of de-allocations must be `N`. You forgot the allocations happening in `make_vector`. Depending on whether copy elision is possible (or we pass a reference to `tmp`) or not, the number of allocations is `N+1` or `2N` and that of the de-allocations `1` or `N`.

Comment: (3) Your analysis of your own technique is also incorrect: You forgot `N` allocations in `make_vector`. Thus your technique really requires `2N` allocations and `N` de-allocations, while `N+1`, `1` is possible, even if `capacity() > size()` in all cases. Your conclusions are therefore also wrong, it's exactly the other way around!

Comment: **`shrink_to_fit()` cannot help here**, not only because it does not guarantee anything, but also because even if it did, it amounts to unnecessary allocations and de-allocation, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @Walter Your opinion (1) is wrong.  `tmp` will not be passed to `make_vector` as a reference, unless the compiler can prove it via the 'as-if' rule, which is unlikely.

Comment: @Walter (1) Copy elision applies to copy-initialization, `tmp = make_vector(i);` is an assignment, not an initialization. (2) The analysis states very clearly in the asssumptions that I do not analyze `make_vector` since (a) its definition is not available and (b) it would contribute nothing to the comparison of the two approaches since use of `make_vector` is identical. (3) See (2). `shrink_to_fit` provides the desired property that capacity is as close as possible to size. It is not guaranteed to do so, but neither is anything else in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189688/1137388), I have the following remarks.

As [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok) said in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189619/1137388), `shrink_to_fit` is not guaranteed to do anything. However, if `shrink_to_fit` allocates the memory for exaclty `size()` number of elements, copy/move the elements, and deallocate the original buffer, then this is exactly what the OP's asked.

My exact answer to Q4, that is,

> > Is there are any way to explicitly suppress moving in the last code snipped [...]?

is: Yes, you can do

```
for(auto i=0; i!=4242; ++i)
  table.push_back(static_cast<const std::vector<big_data_type>&>(make_vector(i)));
```

The `copy` function suggested by the OP could be written as follow.

```
template <typename T>
const T& copy(const T& x) {
    return x;
}
```

and the code becomes

```
for(auto i=0; i!=4242; ++i)
  table.push_back(copy(make_vector(i)));
```

But, honestly, I don't think this is a sensible thing to do.

The best place to make each element `v` of `table` such that `v.size() == v.capacity()` is in `make_vector()`, *if possible*. (As [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189688/1137388) the standard doesn't set any upper bound on capacity.) Then moving the result of `make_vector()` to `table` would be optimal in both senses (memory and speed). The OP's snipped should probably take care of `table.size()` instead.

In summary, the standard doesn't provide any way to force capacity to match size. There was a (sensible, IMHO) [suggestion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!searchin/std-discussion/shrink_to_fit/std-discussion/ts9WlqHtMsc/aTCMGqqnyIMJ) by Jon Kalb to make `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` at least as efficient (with respect to memory usage) as the [shrink_to_fit idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Shrink-to-fit) (which also doesn't guarantee anything). However, some members of the committee were not very keen on it and suggested that people should rather complain with their vendors or implement their own containers and allocation functions.

Comment: sorry for downvoting. This is because your wrong comment regarding my comment to Namfuak's answer. However, I appreciate your answer to Q4 and would like to undo my down-voting. and up-vote instead. However, my vote is locked until you edit this post.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some run time tests with a helper type that counts creation, moving and copying:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct big_data_type {
  double state;
  big_data_type( double d ):state(d) { ++counter; ++create_counter; }
  big_data_type():state(0.) { ++counter; }
  big_data_type( big_data_type const& o ): state(o.state) { ++counter; }
  big_data_type( big_data_type && o ): state(o.state) { ++move_counter; }
  big_data_type& operator=( big_data_type const& o ) {
    state = o.state;
    ++counter;
    return *this;
  }
  big_data_type& operator=( big_data_type && o ) {
    state = o.state;
    ++move_counter;
    return *this;
  }
  static int counter;
  static int create_counter;
  static int move_counter;
};
int big_data_type::move_counter = 0;
int big_data_type::create_counter = 0;
int big_data_type::counter = 0;

std::vector<big_data_type>& make_vector( int i, std::vector<big_data_type>& tmp ) {
  tmp.resize(0);
  tmp.reserve(1000);
  for( int j = 0; j < 10+i/100; ++j ) {
    tmp.emplace_back( 100. - j/10. );
  }
  return tmp;
}
std::vector<big_data_type> make_vector2( int i ) {
  std::vector<big_data_type> tmp;
  tmp.resize(0);
  tmp.reserve(1000);
  for( int j = 0; j < 10+i/100; ++j ) {
    tmp.emplace_back( 100. - j/10. );
  }
  return tmp;
}
enum option { a, b, c, d, e };
void test(option op) {
  std::vector<std::vector<big_data_type> > table;
  std::vector<big_data_type> tmp;
  for(int i=0; i!=10; ++i) {
    switch(op) {
      case a:
        table.emplace_back(make_vector(i, tmp));
        break;
      case b:
        tmp = make_vector2(i);
        table.emplace_back(tmp);
        break;
      case c:
        tmp = make_vector2(i);
        table.emplace_back(std::move(tmp));
        break;
      case d:
        table.emplace_back(make_vector2(i));
        break;
      case e:
        std::vector<big_data_type> result;
        make_vector(i, tmp);
        result.reserve( tmp.size() );
        result.insert( result.end(), std::make_move_iterator( tmp.begin() ),std::make_move_iterator( tmp.end() ) );
        table.emplace_back(std::move(result));
        break;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Big data copied or created:" << big_data_type::counter << "\n";
  big_data_type::counter = 0;
  std::cout << "Big data created:" << big_data_type::create_counter << "\n";
  big_data_type::create_counter = 0;
  std::cout << "Big data moved:" << big_data_type::move_counter << "\n";
  big_data_type::move_counter = 0;
  std::size_t cap = 0;
  for (auto&& v:table)
    cap += v.capacity();
  std::cout << "Total capacity at end:" << cap << "\n";
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "A\n";
  test(a);
  std::cout << "B\n";
  test(b);
  std::cout << "C\n";
  test(c);
  std::cout << "D\n";
  test(d);
  std::cout << "E\n";
  test(e);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4a86b04a21c3044a7096354a85725d14-ce63b00575120a42bc1818a9e42b62ba)

Output:

```
+ g++ -O4 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -std=c++11 main.cpp
+ ./a.out
A
Big data copied or created:200
Big data created:100
Big data moved:0
Total capacity at end:100
B
Big data copied or created:200
Big data created:100
Big data moved:0
Total capacity at end:100
C
Big data copied or created:100
Big data created:100
Big data moved:0
Total capacity at end:10000
D
Big data copied or created:100
Big data created:100
Big data moved:0
Total capacity at end:10000
E
Big data copied or created:100
Big data created:100
Big data moved:100
Total capacity at end:100
```

`E` is an example when your big data can be moved, which often doesn't work.

`created` refers to only explicitly created data (ie, from the `double`) -- data "created on purpose".  Copied or created refers to any time that any big data is duplicated in a way that the source big data cannot be "discarded".  And moved refers to any situation where big data is moved in a way that the source big data can be "discarded".

Case `a` and `b`, which are identical in result, are probably want you are looking for.  Note the explicit use of the `tmp` `vector` as an argument to `make_vector`: elision won't let you reuse the buffer, you have to be explicit about it.

Comment: Nice analysis! However, I don't think that `a` and `b` are equivalent as your analysis suggests. They should differ in the number of allocations & de-allocations.

Comment: So I added some counting (defining an allocator that counts the number of allocations and de-allocations, as well as the total number of bytes allocated) and indeed, `a` is preferable in this respect over `b`, exactly as I thought.

Comment: @Walter I guess it depends on if `std::vector` has self-assignment optimization.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The vector of vectors construct brings a lot of unnecessary overhead in cases where data is only ever added at the end of the top level vector (as appears to be the case here).

The main issue is the separate buffer allocations and management for each individual entry in the top level vector.

It's much better to concatenate all the sub-entries together into a single contiguous buffer, if possible, with a separate buffer to index into this for each top level entry.

See [this article](http://upcoder.com/2/efficient-vectors-of-vectors/) (on my blog), for more discussion about this, and for an example implementation of a 'collapsed vector vector' class to wrap this kind of indexed buffer setup up in a generic container object.

As I said before, this only applies if data only ever gets added *at the end* of your data structure, i.e. you don't come back later and push entries into arbitrary top level sub vectors, but in cases where this technique applied it can be quite a significant optimisation..

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want capacity to equal size you can use vector::shrink_to_fit()
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/

Comment: Which is, unfortunately, not guaranteed to do anything.

Comment: A horrible suggestion! `shrink_to_fit` amounts to re-allocation (allocate+copy+de-allocate). De-allocations are not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I learned a bit, but couldn't really find a complete answer. So let's first clarify the **task**:

We have a function filling in a vector. In order to avoid arguments whether copy elision is possible or not, let's just assume that its definition is

```
void fill_vector(std::vector<big_data_type>& v, int i)
{
  v.clear();
  v.reserve(large_number);       // allocates unless v.capacity() >= large_number
  for(int done=0,k=0; k<large_number && !done; ++k)
    v.push_back(get_more_big_data(i,done));
  // v.capacity() == v.size() is highly unlikely at this point.
}
```

Further we want to fill the table

```
std::vector<std::vector<big_data_type>> table;
```

with `N` entries, each generated by `fill_vector()` in such a way that (1) minimises memory usage in the table but (2) avoids unnecessary allocations/de-allocations. In a simple C code, there would be `N+2` allocations and `1` de-allocation and only the total number `K` of `big_data_type` actually provided by `fill_vector()` would be allocated. We should not need more with C++. Here is a possible C++ **answer**

```
table.reserve(N);                         // allocates enough space for N vectors
size_t K=0;                               // count big_data_types in table
std::vector<big_data_type> tmp;
for(int n=0; n!=N; ++n) {
  fill_vector(tmp,i);                     // allocates at first iteration only
  K += tmp.size();
  table.push_back(tmp.begin(),tmp.end()); // allocates tmp.size() big_data_type
}
                                          // de-allocates tmp
```

Thus we have `N+2` allocations and `1` de-allocation as required and no memory wasted (not more than `K` `big_data_type` allocated in `table`). The `push_back` calls a constructor of `std::vector` (without passing information about the capacity of `tmp`) and implies a copy of each `big_data_type`. (If `big_data_type` can be moved, we could use `make_move_iterator(tmp.begin())` etc.)

Note that no matter how we code this, we must do at least `N+1` allocations (for `table` and each of its elements). This implies that usage of `shrink_to_fit` cannot be helpful, because at best it does one allocation and one de-allocation (unless `capacity==size` which we don't expect to happen with any probability), cancelling each other (so that the allocation cannot contribute towards the required sum of `N+1`). This is why some other answers were unacceptable.